# Mathematically correct definitions

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology, definition

My teacher said that a definition need a  mathematical justification, but I do not understand this...

Is it possible have a wrong definition?

How am I sure that a definition in a mathematical theory is mathematically correct?

How am I sure that an object is well-defined?

Comment: Examples are always a good idea.  If you are going to define something, it helps a lot if you can present some non-trivial examples which satisfy your definition.

Comment: Definitions do not exist in a vacuum and the quality or correctness or other attributes of them are mostly matters of opinion.

Comment: Everything in mathematics needs a "mathematical justification", also a definition. "Can a mathematical definition be wrong" has already been discussed in many duplicates. See for example [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31358/can-a-mathematical-definition-be-wrong).

Comment: Why should we close such an interesting question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Because it has been discussed already many times? Did you see the MO-question? And the formulation of the question there is more to the point, too.

Comment: One of the big concern is the non-vacuity: If I say "let us give the name $S$ to the set of functions having properties a) and b) and c), it may happen that the set of such functions is empty (I know somebody wha had begun a PhD thesis on such a set of functions..

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Thanks. I hadn't seen the MO-question you are refering to because I had begun to type a comment...

Comment: @JeanMarie No problem. I think you are right that the topic is interesting. Maybe the question could be more detailed. So far one can only repeat that some definitions are senseless, because they are vacuous, or that "a careless definition can actually introduce unsoundness into a formal framework".

Comment: @DietrichBurde I just looked at the MO-question (and its answers) and I found it very interesting. However, I don't think there are exactly the same questions. The MO-question does not seem to address the mathematical correctness of a definition (like the OP question here) but rather its accuracy in some given mathematical context. In other words, the MO-question is rather about *good* definitions than *correct* definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How am I sure that an object is well-defined? An object is well-defined if any reader can read the definition and come out with the same object.

Example: Let $f(x)$ be the function such that $f(x)^2=x$. This is not well defined since $\sqrt{x}$ and $-\sqrt{x}$ both work. To make this definition well-defined, we generally choose the first option (although we could choose the second if we wanted).

Comment: It's worth noting that the function which is $\sqrt{x}$ on the nonnegative rationals and $-\sqrt{x}$ on the positive irrationals also satisfies that equation. It might not be worth noting that you didn't specify the domain and codomain of $f$.